# XSLT render string as html with replace function

Tags: xslt

Suppose the following input xml:

```
<div text="This is [BFboldBF]">
</div>
```

The goal is to transform this into this:

```
 <div>
      This is <span class="bold">bold</span> text
 </div>
```

My xsl has the following setting:

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

I tried substitution via the replace function

```
<xsl:variable name="lfL">
  <xsl:text>&lt;span class="bold"&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="close">
  <xsl:text>&lt;span/&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="text" select="@text"/>
<xsl:variable name="lfBT" select="replace($text, '\[BF', $lfL)"/>
<xsl:variable name="rfBT" select="replace($lfBT, 'BF\]', $close)"/>
```

and rendering the text variable via

```
<div>
  <xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</div>
```

this however does not render the xml. Instead it renders it as plain text, with the brackets escaped '&lt';

Comment: The use of `replace` suggests you have XSLT 2 or 3 so in any case, if your task is to analyze/process/parse plain text but to construct nodes like `span` or `b` elements, use `xsl:analyze-string` (in XSLT 2 or 3) or the function `analyze-string` (in XSLT 3) instead of `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid disable-output-escaping, because it won't work in all environments. Not all XSLT processors support it, and some support it only if you run the transformation in a particular way. That's because it requires some out-of-band communication between the XSLT processor and the serializer.

The way to do this is analyse-string:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@text]">
  <div>
    <xsl:analyse-string select="@text" regex="\[BF(.*)BF\]">
      <xsl:on-match>
        <bold><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></bold>
      </xsl:on-match>
      <xsl:on-no-match>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:on-no-match>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Not tested.